# How can I speed up this slow query with the right indexes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
SELECT "items".* FROM "items" 
INNER JOIN item_mods ON item_mods.item_id = items.id 
INNER JOIN mods ON mods.id = item_mods.mod_id 
AND item_mods.mod_id = 3 
WHERE (items.player_id = '1') 
GROUP BY items.id, item_mods.primary_value 
ORDER BY item_mods.primary_value DESC NULLS LAST, items.created_at DESC LIMIT 100
```

This query is currently taking around 7 seconds. I have about 550k records on the items table, ~2.5million records on the `item_mods` table and about 800 records on the mods table. I have quite a few indexes but I am not sure if I am using the right ones.

So if you were to optimize this query what would you recommend?

Here is the explain analysis.

http://explain.depesz.com/s/aiYH

```
"Limit  (cost=107274.88..107275.13 rows=100 width=554) (actual time=6648.872..6648.888 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=107274.88..107419.24 rows=57745 width=554) (actual time=6648.870..6648.879 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: item_mods.primary_value, items.created_at"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 103kB"
"        ->  Group  (cost=104634.82..105067.91 rows=57745 width=554) (actual time=6358.348..6529.342 rows=57498 loops=1)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=104634.82..104779.18 rows=57745 width=554) (actual time=6358.344..6423.184 rows=57498 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: items.id, item_mods.primary_value"
"                    Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 25624kB"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23182.35..71248.94 rows=57745 width=554) (actual time=3339.625..6127.659 rows=57498 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using mods_pkey on mods  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.323..0.324 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (id = 3)"
"                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=23182.35..70663.22 rows=57745 width=558) (actual time=3339.298..6108.202 rows=57498 loops=1)"
"                                Merge Cond: (items.id = item_mods.item_id)"
"                                ->  Index Scan using items_pkey on items  (cost=0.00..45112.64 rows=543004 width=550) (actual time=3.190..2575.715 rows=543024 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (player_id = 1)"
"                                ->  Materialize  (cost=23182.33..23471.20 rows=57774 width=12) (actual time=3336.099..3388.810 rows=57547 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=23182.33..23326.76 rows=57774 width=12) (actual time=3336.095..3370.179 rows=57547 loops=1)"
"                                            Sort Key: item_mods.item_id"
"                                            Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 1240kB"
"                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on item_mods  (cost=1084.27..17622.45 rows=57774 width=12) (actual time=31.728..3263.762 rows=57547 loops=1)"
"                                                  Recheck Cond: (mod_id = 3)"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on primary_value_mod_id_desc  (cost=0.00..1069.83 rows=57774 width=0) (actual time=29.565..29.565 rows=57547 loops=1)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (mod_id = 3)"
"Total runtime: 6652.100 ms"
```

**UPDATE**

I have modified the query as suggested. I was using the GROUP BY to only select 1 item per item ID but I guess distinct works as well. Here is the new query and explain, it still takes too long. The idea of the query is to find all items player '1' has with the item modifier '3' ordered by the modifier with the highest primary value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT("items".id), "item_mods".primary_value, "items".created_at 
FROM "items" INNER JOIN item_mods ON item_mods.item_id = items.id 
INNER JOIN mods ON mods.id = item_mods.mod_id AND item_mods.mod_id = 3 
WHERE (items.player_id = '1') 
ORDER BY item_mods.primary_value DESC NULLS LAST, items.created_at DESC LIMIT 100
```

The explain http://explain.depesz.com/s/t4Zq

```
"Limit  (cost=73737.59..73738.59 rows=100 width=16) (actual time=6450.253..6450.344 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=73737.59..74315.04 rows=57745 width=16) (actual time=6450.248..6450.316 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=73737.59..73881.95 rows=57745 width=16) (actual time=6450.242..6450.272 rows=100 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: item_mods.primary_value, items.created_at, items.id"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1456kB"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=46944.77..68183.71 rows=57745 width=16) (actual time=3018.769..6342.109 rows=57498 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (item_mods.item_id = items.id)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1084.27..18208.45 rows=57774 width=8) (actual time=15.911..3219.086 rows=57547 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using mods_pkey on mods  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.486..0.489 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (id = 3)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on item_mods  (cost=1084.27..17622.45 rows=57774 width=12) (actual time=15.416..3197.257 rows=57547 loops=1)"
"                                Recheck Cond: (mod_id = 3)"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on primary_value_mod_id_desc  (cost=0.00..1069.83 rows=57774 width=0) (actual time=13.517..13.517 rows=57547 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: (mod_id = 3)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=36420.95..36420.95 rows=543004 width=12) (actual time=2987.089..2987.089 rows=543024 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 4096  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 811kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on items  (cost=0.00..36420.95 rows=543004 width=12) (actual time=0.012..2825.650 rows=543024 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: (player_id = 1)"
"Total runtime: 6457.586 ms"
```

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, I think I'm almost there.
This query takes 6 secs and produces what I want

```
SELECT "items".id, item_mods.primary_value
FROM "items" 
INNER JOIN item_mods ON item_mods.item_id = items.id AND item_mods.mod_id = 36 
WHERE (items.player_id = '1') 
ORDER BY item_mods.primary_value DESC, item_mods.id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

But this query takes 9ms! Note the difference in ORDER BY. But I need them ordered by the most recent first. I have an index on (item_mods.primary_value DESC, item_mods.id DESC) but it dosen't seem to be using it?

```
SELECT "items".id, item_mods.primary_value
FROM "items" 
INNER JOIN item_mods ON item_mods.item_id = items.id AND item_mods.mod_id = 36 
WHERE (items.player_id = '1') 
ORDER BY item_mods.primary_value DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Only use * if you really NEED to select all fields

Comment: also, make sure items.player_id, item_mods.item_id, item_mods.mod_id all have their own idex

Comment: How is it possible to select `*` when you have a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: first remove group by items.id if items.id is unique, second why are you using group by without agregate functions?

Comment: Also, check that your primary keys are integers where possible, if nothing helps think about denormalization.

Comment: @enterx: actually before normalization OP needs to think about rewriting query to something that would make sense :-S `ORDER BY item_mods.primary_value` clause is completely weird

Comment: I think you need to tell us what the query is supposed to *do*, i.e. what the logic, the intention here is. Just banging some extra indexes in may help, but it's likely there's a much better way to phrase such a query. (Mazzy, just creating indexes on fields rarely helps, and certainly isn't based on any evidence shown here).

Comment: Updated the question with logic, new query and explain

Comment: `external merge  Disk: 1456kB`. `SET work_mem = '50MB'` and re-try. Also, is there an index on `items(player_id)`?

Comment: http://explain.depesz.com/s/ikHo Here is the new explain after running the above query. Some improvement but not enough. I'm sure postgres can do better?

Comment: Yes I have this index
CREATE INDEX index_items_on_player_id
  ON items
  USING btree
  (player_id);

Comment: Updated question again, Ive narrowed the problem down to a single order by

Comment: @zerkms you're right. seem to me too that something, in plural, isn't right with the query too.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the index (mod_id, primary_value desc, id desc) to the item_mods table. The query now runs in 10-15ms

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using the Postgres "feature" that you can group by the primary/unique key in a table and then select all columns from that table.  Otherwise, `select *` would not make sense in an aggregation query.

```
SELECT "items".*
FROM "items"  INNER JOIN
     item_mods
     ON item_mods.item_id = items.id INNER JOIN
     mods
     ON mods.id = item_mods.mod_id AND item_mods.mod_id = 3 
WHERE (items.player_id = '1') 
GROUP BY items.id, item_mods.primary_value 
ORDER BY item_mods.primary_value DESC NULLS LAST, items.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

The following indexes should help this query:

```
items(player_id, id)
item_mods(item_id, mod_id);
mods(id);
```

Comment: I have these indexes. I assume mods(id) is already indexed as its a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Use composite indexes.

What is an index?

Index is a special block of information about data in the table which demands updating on every update of the table that contain that index which means if you're constantly updating the data of the index's table indexes can have a negative impact on performance.

The positive sides are reduced search/sort/group time.

What is a composite index?
Composite index is a special block of information that can be considered as sorted array which rows consist data made by concatenation of values of all the columns that key is made of. The composite key consist only of columns of a single table (MySQL, not certain for others!) and it accelerates multiple sorts of queries made against a single table.

What a potential candidates(columns) for an index?
Those that are used for search(select), group and sort (order).

Is there a way to force/ignore an index use?
Yes. (MySQL!)

What are potential candidates for an index? How to find then?
The columns from the queries whose performance is regarded as - slow.